# Azure WebApi JsonSerializerSettings behaving differently

Tags: c#, json.net, azure-web-app-service

On Thursday, 12/14 before 1:15pm CST, JSON serialization/deserialization behaved as expected on my Azure WebApi service. However, after that time, it seems as though our setting in the WebApiConfig.cs:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
};
```

seems to be ignored, and now, when we serialize to json, we're getting properties with null values.

We're using .Net Framework 4.8.

On another, pre-production, instance of our service, that setting still seems to be respected, so we don't see properties serialized that have null values.

We had no changes to the service around that time, so it seems to be an infrastructure change.

What types of changes could have been made that would change the behavior of this setting?

Comment: Please share your source code.

Comment: One question I have is: did Azure App Services start using System.Text.Json as its basis, whereas it was using Newtonsoft before last Thursday?

Comment: Based on the framework or version it will change.Have you changed your version of the app?

Comment: No updates were made around the time that things changed